# Best practices for resuming a script

Tags: powershell

I have a script that processes a couple of thousand files and copies the files individual users folders.  This process takes some time as it checks for proper security on each folder and if the user associated with the file still has a valid account.  Because this takes time, there has been instances where the script was closed inadvertently while it was in the middle of processing.

Has anyone come up with a method to check if the script did not finish completely and if so continue processing where it left off?

I was thinking to add a check for a file at the start of the script and if it doesn't exist create the file.  The last part of the script would remove the file.  That way if the script  was closed without finishing the file would exist on the next run and it would 'know' to continue.

I'm just looking for advice on any method that would be better that this.

Comment: Perhaps you can schedule your script to run at night if no users are logged in to accidentally stop the script?

Comment: It's actually an interactive script with a GUI.  The users that initiate it are not always the best at 'letting it run'.  That's why I need to find a 'continue where I left off' solution.

Comment: Log the current activity.

Comment: Ah, ok, so that option is a no-go.

Comment: Every time you finish a part of the task (e.g. processing a single user folder, or an nth-level subfolder), append its name and the current time to a "progress" data file. When you start the application, load this file and look for any entries that are valid (e.g. less than 24 hours old or whatever) and skip over those folders when you come to them because you already did them recently. There's probably a bit more housekeeping needed for the edge cases, but the basic idea should work.

Comment: Even though I have never personally used them, I think [`Workflows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/sma/overview-powershell-workflows?view=sc-sma-2019) might be something you could consider. It allows you to set up checkpoints and they're meant for long running scripts so, it sounds quite similar to what you have.

Comment: There is no common answer for this as the design for this depends on the actual scenario, the speed of enumerating the CI's, checking, filtering, processing and finalizing them. In general, I would use file (flag) that is *supposed* to be in sync with the actual status only as a last resort, instead, it is better to look for an existing handle that *confirms* the actual status. But again, this is specific to your issue and requires more insight.

Comment: If you're comfortable falling back to C# then, although I've not personally done it myself, there could be some solution here using [Queue<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-5.0) to enqueue items first and dequeue them as they are processed. Then you could serialize the pertinent parts of the [FileSystemInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo?view=net-5.0) i.e. FullPath of the directory or file to a file when queuing/dequeuing items. Then when you restart check if the file has anything left to process.

Comment: Another option, if you're using Windows Forms for your GUI, is to add a [Form Closing Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.closing?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) for when the user doesn't let the underlying script do it's job. If you saved an list of the filepaths, again you could save it to file on closure. You can then read the file list and iterate through that.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the tips.  I am most likely going to try the "progress" file option and keep a running log as items are processed.  As I move forward I will investigate Workflows as I now have some very long running scripts that may benefit from this.

Comment: For [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.1#modules-not-shipped-for-powershell-core) reason, I wouldn't put effort into workflows.